# Using 7zip to extract multiple zips in multiple folders

Tags: zip, 7-zip, unzip

I have a large folder tree. Let's say there are folders named A, B, C, etc. through Z.
Inside each folder are a number of zip files.

I can select all the zips in a folder, right click, select 7zip, and select Extract to "*" and it works perfectly. For example if I do that with the zips in folder A, A will contain a folder for each zip with the contents of the zip inside.

What I want to do is do a search for all zip files in ALL folders (A-Z) and perform this operation all at once, such that each of the folders (A-Z) end up with folders for all the zips they contain.

What actually happens is that 7zip extracts everything to the first folder it encounters (say, A).

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work just the way I wanted. The correct command is:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b/a:d') do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x ".\%%g\*.zip" -o"%g\*" -aos
```

Comment: If anyone is trying to use this without it creating a folder where the zip is nested with the same folder name twice, so two folders deep same name, change '-o"%g\*"' to '-o"%g"' . Also, for those wondering, the '-aos' added here tells 7zip to overwrite any files with duplicate names without asking

Answer (score 3):

You could use the windows command line. Just hit the windows logo, type `cmd` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then move to the directory containing the sub-directories with your zip files by typing `cd c:\my\example\dir` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, if it is on another drive, type  e.g. `i:` and again <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to switch to that drive. Now, the correct path shall be shown before the cursor. Then type

```
for /F "usebackq" %f in (`dir /b/a:d`) do @echo %f
```

and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. `dir /b/a:d` returns one row per directory. For each of these rows, the command behind `do` is executed. `@echo %f` will simply write the found names   on your screen, so you can safely control what would be executed if you removed `@echo`. In your case, you'll need something like

```
for /F "usebackq" %f in (`dir /b/a:d`) do C:\APPS\7-Zip\7z.exe x .\%f\*.zip -o%f
```

which will for each sub-directory, call 7zip command line executable (you will need to adjust the path from `C:\APPS\7-Zip\` to your system) and extract all zip files including their full path into the current sub-dir. More info on the 7zip syntax can be found at https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

In case you do this over and over again, you may create a simple *.bat/*.cmd file with above mentioned commando, but you will most likely need to replace % by %% to make it work.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but it's super cool. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, hi Georg, I finally got around to trying this. It doesn't do quite what I want. I tried tweaking it but have had little luck.

/F "usebackq" %f in (`dir /b/a:d`) do C:\APPS\7-Zip\7z.exe x .\%f\*.zip -o%f   does indeed go through each folder and unzip all the files in each folder. What I want, though, is for them to unzin into *subfolders* in each folder that have the same name as the zip file.

Comment: [cont. due to char limit]

For instance, if I have c:\big\a, c:\big\b, c:\big\c, etc. and the zip files in each folder are named a1.zip, a2.zip, a3.zip, b1.zip, b2.zip, etc., I want the zip in c:\big\a to zip into folders c:\big\a\a1, a:\big\a\a2, etc. Currently they all just unzip into z:\big\a.

I tried [for /F "usebackq" %f in (`dir /b/a:d`) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x .\%f\*.zip -o*%f], and now it unzips each zip file into a folder with the same name as the zip file, but *all in the main folder i.e. c:\big\, not insize c:\big\a.

Comment: [cont. due to char limit]

What would be the correct command line for 7zip to make it do what I need? Vere grateful for your attention and time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows navigate to the root folder with the folders A, B, C & D then search `*.zip` or `*.rar` in windows search then select/highlight all the zips and use 7-zip to do whatever you want. Should work just fine with dolphin(linux) as well.

Comment: No, as I said in the OP, the folder for each of the zips will end up in one folder, in my experience, the first folder 7zip encounters.  I want the folder created for each zip to be inside the folder where the zip was i.e. if the zip was in folder D, I want a folder zipfile1234 to be created in folder D.